# UEFI Grub fails to boot encrypted Ubuntu 21.04 system: can't find command `cryptomount'

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, encryption, luks

I am manually (i.e. via custom scripts) installing an Ubuntu 21.04 system.

My GPT disk has two partitions.  An EFI System Partition, and a LUKS (version 1) encrypted BTRFS partition.

On boot, `grub` flashes the following error messages, and then drops to a `grub` prompt.

```
error: file `/boot' not found.
error: no such device: /.disk/info.
error: no such device: /.disk/mini-info.
error: can't find command `cryptomount'.
```

My question is: how do I provide/activate the `cryptomount` command inside Grub?

(If I type `help` at the `grub` prompt, the command `cryptomount` is not listed.)

Interestingly, if I add a type `ef02` BIOS boot partition, and install the BIOS version of Grub, and boot the system in BIOS mode, the boot will succeed.  However, I want the disk to boot on a UEFI system.

Background information:

I have looked at the instructions at the below link, and I don't see anything else I need to do to enable the `cryptomount` command.  I tried adding `insmod cryptomount` to `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg`, but that did not work.

https://cryptsetup-team.pages.debian.net/cryptsetup/encrypted-boot.html

Previously, I have manually installed Ubuntu with a plaintext `/boot` partition and an encrypted `/` partition, and everything worked.  So the new element is that I am trying to put the `/boot` directory on the encrypted `/` partition.  I have also installed Void Linux with `/boot` on an encrypted partition, and that worked as expected.

`/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg` is:

```
cryptomount -u e5f6f8f5dc3944cbb6d8d99b1f17b343
search.fs_uuid 5e42bb87-3342-48b6-aff5-f2519063f9b9 root 
cryptouuid/e5f6f8f5dc3944cbb6d8d99b1f17b343 
set prefix=($root)'/@_2107_hirsute/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

I install `grub` by running the following:

```
opts=''
opts="$opts  --force"
opts="$opts  --no-floppy"
opts="$opts  --recheck"
opts="$opts  --removable"

opts="$opts  --target=x86_64-efi"
opts="$opts  --efi-directory=/boot/efi"
opts="$opts  --bootloader-id=Ubuntu"

chroot  /mnt  grub-install  $opts
```

Comment: Typically you need a /boot partition outside of the encrypted volume. There are ways to avoid it but it's very complex and IMHO not worth the time.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  I believe my question stated that I was already fully familiar with the plaintext `/boot` approach.  I disagree with your assessment that the solution is "very complex".  The solution is actually very simple (albeit obscure and hard to find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that running the following commands (as root), in the following order, inside the installation chroot environment, will generate Grub files in `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/` that will allow Grub to read the kernel and the `initrd.img` file from the `/boot` directory on the encrypted `/` partition.

```
#  echo  'GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y'  >>  /etc/default/grub
#  apt-get  install  -y  --reinstall  grub-efi-amd64-signed
#  update-initramfs  -c  -k all
#  grub-install  /dev/vda
#  update-grub
```

Soucre:  https://mutschler.eu/linux/install-guides/ubuntu-btrfs/#install-the-efi-bootloader

Previously, I was running most or all of the above commands, but in a different order.

Afterwards, the files look like this:

```
# ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT
total 1680
-rwx------ 1 root root 1718144 Jul 17 16:08 BOOTX64.EFI
-rwx------ 1 root root     224 Jul 17 06:13 grub.cfg

# cat /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg 
cryptomount -u a771eeddca6942c0be0ac88852a9b45b
search.fs_uuid ae60b399-84bd-4a08-b0aa-7f33a847b873 root 
cryptouuid/a771eeddca6942c0be0ac88852a9b45b 
set prefix=($root)'/@_2107_hirsute/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Your files may look different depending upon how you have partitioned and mounted your disks.

Prior to running the above commands in the above order, the `BOOTX64.EFI` file was 1.4M, whereas now it is 1.7M.

I don't know of any way (other than trying a reboot) to look inside the `BOOTX64.EFI` and verify that it actually contains the `cryptodisk` module.